# Custom Template Hide Parent element of empty content area?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, custom

I'm developing custom templates which a non technical person has to fill up the contents (only text & images). In my case, primary content area going to have any 1 of 3 types of content styles(*refer code below), but they want all 3 styles inside the template(without texts & images). So, I want to hide the main parent element of the empty content area.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
<!-- Style-1 -->
<td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#f9f7f0" style="">
  <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="subContainer">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:10px;line-height:36px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
        <custom type="content" name"Content Area-1 Title">
      </td>
      <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:24px;font:15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#82785e; font-weight:normal; line-height:18px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" class="">
                <custom type="content" name"Content Area-1 Description">
      </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way (that I know of) to script for content inside a defined template Content Area from outside the content area.

Here are a couple paths that I've taken with complex email builds:

1. Build templates with one editable content area that's an AMPScript block.  Have the deployment person set the variable values. The template scripting itself would hide or show content based on the AMPScript variables set in the `Init` content area.
2. Build and store your *base* content areas and have the deployment folks just "retrieve and tweak" them for each email build.  The template would just consist of a header, several content areas and a footer.
3. If the email is too technical, then invest in documentation and training.